How to request API in Capacitor App created in Nuxt.js
I get error
/**
     * API is not available.
     *
     * This means the API can't be used right now because:
     *   - it is currently missing a prerequisite, such as network connectivity
     *   - it requires a particular platform or browser version

I created Capacitor App by existing Nuxt.js project and use dist folder which is generated by executing nuxt generate. When I run App, API request respond html file below
var ExceptionCode;
(function (ExceptionCode) {
    /**
     * API is not implemented.
     *
     * This usually means the API can't be used because it is not implemented for
     * the current platform.
     */
    ExceptionCode["Unimplemented"] = "UNIMPLEMENTED";
    /**
     * API is not available.
     *
     * This means the API can't be used right now because:
     *   - it is currently missing a prerequisite, such as network connectivity
     *   - it requires a particular platform or browser version

I have backend at /server/api/XYZ.js
for example /server/api/proxy.js
import { defineEventHandler, getQuery } from 'h3';
import axios from 'axios';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { url } = getQuery(event);

  if (!url) {
    event.res.statusCode = 400;
    return { error: 'Missing URL parameter' };
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
      },`your text`
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching the URL:', error);
    event.res.statusCode = 500;
    return { error: 'Failed to fetch the URL' };
  }
});

it returns me the HTML of the desired page and I use it like
const fetchShops = async () => {
    try {
        isLoading.value = true;
        const response = await axios.get('/api/proxy', {
            params: {
                url: 'XYZ.com',
            },
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        isLoading.value = false;
        console.error('Error fetching shops:', error);
    }
}

In Android Studio in Logcat, I get the log:
Handling local request: http://localhost:3000/api/proxy?url=XYZ.com

I don't get any data from backend?
